# Unix process parent pointer's pid isn't what I'm expecting

Tags: c, unix, process, kernel, freebsd

I'm writing kernel code for FreeBSD for an assignment, and I'm having an issue with processes and their parents.

My driver code looks like this:

```
    int pid ;
    const char *sem_name  = "Semaphore1\0";

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        printf("ERROR FAILED TO FORK.");
        return 1;
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        // child
        sleep(10);
        syscall( 293, sem_name );
    } else {
       // parent
       syscall( 292, sem_name, 6 );
       syscall( 293, sem_name );

    }

    return 0;
```

And my syscall (293) that outputs parent pids looks like:

```
  struct proc        *parent_ptr;    // holds pointer to parent

  err = copyinstr( SCARG(uap, name), &kname, MAX_STR_LENGTH, &knamesize );
  if (err == EFAULT)
    return( err );

  // p is the pointer to the proc that called the syscall
  uprintf("Current process pid: %d\n", p->p_pid);

  parent_ptr = p;
  n_sem = malloc( (u_long)sizeof( struct n_semaphore ), M_FREE, M_NOWAIT );

  while (parent_ptr->p_pptr != NULL) {
     uprintf("parentid : %d\n", parent_ptr->p_pid);
     LIST_FOREACH( n_sem, &parent_ptr->p_semaphores, next ) {
         uprintf("-sem name: %s count %d\n", n_sem->name, n_sem->count);
     }
     parent_ptr = parent_ptr->p_pptr;
  }
```

The output I get from the driver looks like:

```
// parent 
Current process pid: 4682
parentid : 4682
parentid : 10895
parentid : 1
// child
Current process pid: 18710
parentid : 18710
parentid : 1
```

Syscall 292 just created the semaphore and adds it to a processes semaphore queue, but that isn't the issue for me so I left it out.

It seems like the child process has a smaller parent tree than the process that forks it? This doesn't make sense to me. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just for commentary (not an answer), I'm surprised a process has more than one parent.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry I was unclear, those would be the pid of each process' parent, so a process has only one parent, I am just iterating over each parent's parent.

Comment: but parent is not calling the syscall 293?

Comment: @MK. sorry about that, it does, I'll adjust the code to be more accurate, I made a mistake in copying it over

Comment: Could it be that the parent process of 18710 has exited by the time you're looking at it, so that it has been inherited by `init`, PID 1?  Is 4682 still valid after you look at 18710?  Is 4682 the parent of 18710?

Comment: That's what I was thinking. The first process exits, the child is orphaned, and it's parent is now 1. I added more forks and it seems to catch on now, but I was hoping to get it to work in the case of just one fork.

Comment: With the `sleep(10)` in the child  you are ensuring the parent is gone by the time the client is executing _syscall 293_. You would need to put sleeps before and after the _sycall 293_ calls to allow the processes to see each other by the time of calling.

Comment: You could have the parent wait(2) for its child to die...